# Adding clause criteria based on logged in user to custom button

Tags: javascript, custom-button

I need to add an statement into this custom button so that it only runs if it meets a certain, how would I do this?

The statement essentially needs to say if the logged in user is equal to the R_D_Service_Owner__c or the project_owner__c then it can run, or if the logged in user profile equals 'system administrator' it can run, or if the logged in user equals a specific user id, or another specific user id it can run.

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/19.0/connection.js")}
   var proName = '{!$Profile.Name}'; 
   var userId = '{!$User.Id}';
   var proOwnerId = '{!Product2.Project_Owner__c}';
   var serOwnerId = '{!Product2.R_D_Service_Owner__c}';

if(proName.includes("Administrator")||proOwnerId==userId||serOwnerId==userId){ 
var r = new sforce.SObject("Product2");
r.id = "{!Product2.Id}";
r.Convert_to_Service_Catalogue__c = true;
result = sforce.connection.update([r]);


if ( result[0].getBoolean( "success" ) ) {

window.location.reload(); // refresh page

} else {

var errors = result[0].errors;
var errorMessages = "The Lifecycle Status must be Beta, and the following
fields must be populated; Name, Unique ID, Jisc Directorate, Include in   
Dashboard, Service/Project Owner or else this record won't be converted to a    
Service Catalogue record";

for ( var i = 0; i < errors.length; i++ ) {
errorMessages += errors[i].message + '\n';
}

alert( errorMessages ); // display all validation errors

}
}
else{
    alert("You are not eligible for this operation!"); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/19.0/connection.js")}
var proName = '{!$Profile.Name}'; 
var userId = '{!$User.Id}';
var proOwnerId = '{!Your_object_API__c.project_owner__c}';
if(proName.includes("Administrator") && proName==userId){ 
var r = new sforce.SObject("Product2");
r.id = "{!Product2.Id}";
r.Convert_to_Service_Catalogue__c = true;
result = sforce.connection.update([r]);


if ( result[0].getBoolean( "success" ) ) {

window.location.reload(); // refresh page

} else {

var errors = result[0].errors;
var errorMessages = "The Lifecycle Status must be Beta, and the following
fields must be populated; Name, Unique ID, Jisc Directorate, Include in   
Dashboard, Service/Project Owner or else this record won't be converted to a    
Service Catalogue record";

for ( var i = 0; i < errors.length; i++ ) {
    errorMessages += errors[i].message + '\n';
}

alert( errorMessages ); // display all validation errors

}
}
else{
    alert("You are not eligible for this operation!"); 
}
```

Basically, you can do it like that.

You can extend your if criteria.

Comment: how would I do the bit to compare if project_owner__c.id equal to current logged in user id? @umithuckan

Comment: updated the answer

Comment: can you update your answer please, what I have written isn't working. apologies I'm very new to this :)

Comment: @umitthuckan it doesn't like the terms || or && in an if statement, any idea?

Comment: i just tried this and it worked for me.
if(proName.includes("Administrator") && 1==1){

Can you paste your latest code?

Comment: i've edited my question to include the most recent code. It displays the error 'invalid or unexpected token'